# Flask/sqlalchemy | 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project for one of my courses at college. The project is a web application using flask and python to create the web application. I am having an issue with my project and the error I am returned is AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'query' which refers to this line in my code "pagination = transaction.query.paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)".

transaction init file

```
import csv
import logging
import os

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort, url_for,current_app
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

from app.db import db
from app.db.models import transaction
from app.transactions.forms import csv_upload
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename, redirect

transaction = Blueprint('transaction', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@transaction.route('/transactions', methods=['GET'], defaults={"page": 1})
@transaction.route('/transactions/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def transaction_browse(page):
    page = page
    per_page = 1000
    pagination = transaction.query.paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)
    data = pagination.items
    try:
        return render_template('browse_transactions.html',data=data,pagination=pagination)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

app init file

```
"""A simple flask web app"""
import os

import flask_login
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_mail import Mail

from app.auth import auth
from app.simple_pages import simple_pages
from app.cli import create_database
from app.db import database
from app.db import db
from app.db.models import User
from app.error_handlers import error_handlers
from app.logging_config import log_con, LOGGING_CONFIG
from app.context_processors import utility_text_processors
from app.transactions import transaction

mail = Mail()

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()

def create_app():
    """Create and configure an instance of the Flask application."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "production":
        app.config.from_object("app.config.ProductionConfig")
    elif os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "development":
        app.config.from_object("app.config.DevelopmentConfig")
    elif os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "testing":
        app.config.from_object("app.config.TestingConfig")
    app.mail = Mail(app)

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"

    csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

    bootstrap = Bootstrap5(app)
    app.register_blueprint(simple_pages)
    app.register_blueprint(auth)
    app.register_blueprint(database)
    app.register_blueprint(log_con)
    app.register_blueprint(error_handlers)
    app.register_blueprint(transaction)
    app.context_processor(utility_text_processors)
    app.cli.add_command(create_database)
    db.init_app(app)

    api_v1_cors_config = {
        "methods": ["OPTIONS", "GET", "POST"],
    }
    CORS(app, resources={"/api/*": api_v1_cors_config})

    return app

@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    except:
        return None
```

database models init file

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from app.db import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin
Base = declarative_base()

transaction_user = db.Table('transaction_user', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('transaction_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('transaction.id'))
)

class transaction(db.Model,SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True, unique=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="transaction", uselist=False)

    def __init__(self, type, amount):
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
```

Comment: You have a class named transaction and a blueprint named transaction. Rename one of them

Comment: I just found out that the class and blueprint name were the same right before I saw your reply. Thank you so much @GonzaloOdiard !